# pass string parameter in an onclick call

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Hi all im having major issues with this line of php code, Im trying to pass the name of a php variable (unique to that div) through to a javascript function on the click of that div. However I keep getting the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". This is the code:

```html
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $classname = $row["classname"];
                    $classcode = $row["corsecode"];
                    $color = $row["Color"];
                    echo '<div class="classsec" onclick="newpage('.$classname.')"> <p class="p3" style="  text-decoration: underline wavy '.$color.';">'.$classcode.'</p></div>';
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you please share more of your code? (couple of rows upper) - and mark on the code on exactly which line you get that error

Comment: replace - (" '.$classname.' " ) , " ' .$color.' ", " '.$classcode.' "

Answer (score -1):

If the value of `$classname` will contain various characters and not just numbers, then you will need to wrap the value in escaped 's when passing it through a JS function from onClick events. Otherwise, this will generate the error you mentioned

> [error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"]

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $classname = $row["classname"];
                $classcode = $row["corsecode"];
                $color = $row["Color"];
                echo '<div class="classsec" onclick="newpage(\''.$classname.'\')"> <p class="p3" style="  text-decoration: underline wavy '.$color.';">'.$classcode.'</p></div>';
            }
        }
        ?>
```